# How to call public sub using button in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, subroutine

In VB.Net, how can I call the`Public Sub` using a button click?

Here's what I have so far:

```
Public Sub SetThreshold(ByVal e As PaintEventArgs)

    ' Open an Image file, and draw it to the screen.
    Dim Image As New Bitmap(PictureBox1.Image)
    PictureBox1.Image = Image
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(Image, 20, 20)

    ' Create an ImageAttributes object, and set its color threshold.
    Dim imageAttr As New ImageAttributes
    imageAttr.SetThreshold(0.7F)

    ' Draw the image with the colors bifurcated.
    Dim rect As New Rectangle(300, 20, 200, 200)
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(Image, rect, 0, 0, 200, 200, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, imageAttr)
End Sub
```

Comment: What you are asking is quite a basic concept.  It might be a good idea for you to learn a bit more about the language you are using before asking any more questions.

Comment: But wouldn't asking a question point a direction of what concepts to explore next in the language? Seems a bit odd to tell someone trying to learn something new not to ask questions.

Comment: I think what he's probably suggesting is to consider asking that question at google.com and see what you find.

Comment: Good point on google

Comment: You need to call your method from an event handler on the button. Here's something to get you started: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/vb.net/vb.net_button.htm. It would be easier if you probably used Graphics as your parameter instead of the PaintEventArgs, then just pass your target graphics object.

Comment: I got it. Thanks for helping :)